# How to set a range using values from referenced cells?

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am trying to construct a macro to fill a certain number of blank cells after the end of my filled cells with zeros. This macro cycles through all of the sheets in the workbook (except the first sheet, which is named in the code). My code is below:

```
    NumSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count  

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    First = LastRow(sh)

    If IsError(Application.Match(sh.Name, _
        Array("ECG_Log (root)"), 0)) Then
        For i = 1 To (NumSh - 1)
            LastVal = i + 4
            Last = Worksheets("ECG_Log (root)").Cells(LastVal, 12).Value
            'MsgBox (First)
            Set ZerRng = sh.Range(Cells(First, 1), Cells(Last, 2))
               '^^this is where is throws the 1004: range of object failed 
                   'error
            Range(ZerRng).Value = 0
        Next i
    End If
 Next

End Sub



Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
On Error Resume Next
LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Ideally, I would like to open each worksheet, find the last row ("First"), and define a range from that last row to the value ("Last") from a cell on the first sheet. It seems that the correct values are being found for First and Last, but I am still catching an error when trying to define my range for zeros. Any suggestions?

Comment: The obvious mistake: change to **Set ZerRng = sh.Range(sh.Cells(First, 1), sh.Cells(Last, 2))**.

Comment: The code will also fail with the 1004 error if `Last` is empty.

Comment: @Spring Filip: But I would bet that rather the Function LastRow is returning something wrong. I wonder if the next row is already added (First = LastRow(sh)+1?)?

Comment: Agreed. @kshayeo, could you please update question and provide the `LastRow` function?

Comment: Hi all, Sorry for the hiatus. @VBasic2008 you got it. I think I was staring at it too long and missed that...hate when that happens.  @Spring Filip I was able to check that it was finding the correct value for `Last` from the range defined on Sheet1. The LastRow function (I believe) is correct - I will edit the post if anyone is interested. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Fill zeros

```vb
Sub FillZeros()
    
    Const cSheet As String = "ECG_Log (root)" ' Source Worksheet Name
    Const cFer As Long = 4          ' Source Above First Row Number
    Const cCol As Variant = 12      ' Source Column Letter/Number ("L")
    Const cCols As String = "A:B"   ' Target Columns Address
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet   ' Target Worksheet
    Dim Fer As Long       ' Target First Empty Row
    Dim Lr As Long        ' Target Last Row
    Dim i As Long         ' Source Row Counter
    
    ' Loop through worksheets in this workbook (workbook containing this code).
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Check if name of current Target Worksheet is NOT equal to Source
        ' Worksheet Name.
        If ws.Name <> cSheet Then
            ' Increase (count) Source Row.
            i = i + 1
            ' Calculate current Target First Empty Row using LastRow function.
            Fer = LastRow(ws) + 1
            ' Calculate Target Last Row i.e. retrieve value from cell at
            ' current row and Source Column of Source Worksheet.
            Lr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet).Cells(i + cFer, cCol).Value
            ' In Current Target Columns
            With ws.Columns(cCols)
                ' Prevent error if already done.
                On Error Resume Next
                    ' Calcutate Target Range.
                    ' Write zeros to Target Range.
                    .Rows(Fer).Resize(Lr - Fer + 1) = 0
                ' Reset error.
                On Error GoTo 0
            End With
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Function LastRow(ws As Worksheet) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
        ' The After argument's default parameter is the left upper cell of
        ' Expression (range) i.e. A1 in this case.
        ' The LookAt and MatchCase arguments are not important because of
        ' What:="*".
        LastRow = ws.Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```